Minerd http request failed: empty reply
I'm trying to run minderd with the following command (I'll replace my email address with EMAIL)
./minerd -o http://btc.kryptex.network:7777 -u EMAIL/worker -a sha256d -R 2

but getting the error "HTTP request failed: empty response from server" I tried to run it without http:// but same result.
I can ping btc.kryptex.network from the server. Also tried btc.kryptex.com.
What can it be?
Ubuntu 24.04.01 Xeon Gold 6148
Probably not very efficient for mining anyway I guess, but is there a better miner program to use to utilize the CPU above?

You cannot mine BTC using just a CPU, it is just orders of magnitude too slow. Even if there was a pool out there that supported such slow contributors, you'd make around ~2 sats per year with a 100 MHash/s CPU (a rough guess), or 2 USD per 1000 years. You need specialized ASICs.

@PieterWuille: Your comment would be fine as an answer.
